# Are there any problems with this Boolean based C programming question?

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean

I'm currently learning about the Boolean data type, and I'm wondering if the conditions in the if-else statements are complete...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main() {
    bool a = false, b = false, c = false , d = false;
    if ((a&&b)||(!c&&d)) {
        if(((a||!b)&&c)||(b&&!a)) {
            printf("1");
        } else if ((a||(d&&b))&& !b) {
            printf("2");
        } else {
            printf("3");
        }
    } else {
        if(!(d&&c)&&(!a)) {
            printf("4");
        } else {
            printf("5");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't the conditions in the if-else statements have a comparison? For example (a&&b)*==true* || (!c&&d)*==true*. Running the program as it is outputs a "4" and I'm a bit confused as to why. Thank you

Comment: The `&&` and `||` operators treat their operands as booleans and return booleans. There's no need to explicitly compare with `true`.

Comment: @Barmar They evaluate to `int`

Comment: @M.M Which is what boolean is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand how the code executes and gives the final result, the key is to understand the operator precedence.

Among the three logic operators, namely **logic not** `!`, **logic and** `&&` ,and **logic or** `||`, **logic not** `!` has the highest precedence, then **logic and** `&&` and then comes **logic or** `||`. 

The **logic not** `!` has a higher precedence than **logic and** `&&` and **logic or** `||`, so the `a&&b` and `!c&&d` both evaluate to `false`.

Because `(a&&b)||(!c&&d)` evaluates to false, the outer `if` body doesn't execute.

Now, it comes into the outer else section.

`d&&c` evaluates to false because both `d` and `c` are false. As a result, `!(d&&c)` evaluates to true. Of course **not a** `!a` evaluates to true too.

In the end, `!(d&&c)&&(!a)` is true. So `printf("4");` executes and output a `4`

Comment: Ohh, thank you! I thought that if it explicitly == "false" or "true" then it will execute. So if-else statements only execute when the **boolean** values is **true**.

Comment: @shafana123 Yes, you are right. If section executes only if when the expression in the parentheses after ```if``` evaluates to true ```if(expression)```, or the ```else``` section will be executed.